How to move next line when cursor before semicolon in css like Sublime Text in VS code
In Sublime Text when we press enter with the cursor immediately before a trailing semicolon, it takes cursor to new line in the same way it does in VS code but with Ctrl + Enter.
Here's the link to forum where they mentioned about it.
https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/st4-bad-cursor-placement-after-auto-completing-a-css-property/58397/7
Where I can add this functionality, so no Ctrl + Enter, but just Enter when the cursor is immediately before a trailing semicolon in CSS or Sass files.


with the extension I made Extra Context, you can use the context variable extraContext:editorCursorNextChar to change the command bound to the Enter key when the next char is a ;
